# physicsBody contactDidBegin not being called?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

in my code I have physics bodies set up for ball and welding sprites.

here is the physicsBody setup for ball sprites:

```
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
ball.physicsBody.velocity = velocity;
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
ball.physicsBody.friction = 0;
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory | barrierCategory | weldCategory | weldPointCategory;
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = weldingCategory;
```

and this is the physicsBody setup for welding sprites:

```
weldRU = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
weldRU.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:weldRU.size];
//weldRU.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
weldRU.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
weldRU.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = weldingCategory;
weldRU.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
weldRU.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
weldRU.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

in the setup I give each other `categoryBitMask`'s and `contactTestBitMask`'s but the contact override method never gets called when these bodies come in contact. the welding sprites do have actions running at any possible contact time but the physicsBody is always present. So am I missing something that is causing them to not detect contact?

Comment: Oh I feel stupid, i forgot to add self.physicsWorld.contactDeligate = self; to the didMoveToView method. Problem solved.

Comment: Then add this solution as the answer and accept it.